# Tools to collect metrics from Kafka

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, admin, operations, network-monitoring

What tools or methods are available for collecting runtime metrics from Kafka brokers?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka exposes its metrics through *JMX*. You can for example use `JMXTrans` to get those metrics and push them to `statsd`/`graphite` or any other [writer](https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans/wiki/OutputWriters).